# Remote desktop to shutdown

Tags: java

I made a program to monitor the active machines in a networked place and perfectly displayed the IP addresses to JList(jList1). When I clicked one of the IP address that is on the list then right clicked the mouse, a JPopupMenu will appear with a menu of "Shutdown". When i tried to click the "shutdown" menu from the popup menu there's an error displayed, says:

```
Apr 14, 2011 1:57:07 PM UsernamePasswordPackage.NetCafeTime$9 actionPerformed SEVERE: null java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported operating system.
        at UsernamePasswordPackage.NetCafeTime.shutdown(NetCafeTime.java:359)
        at UsernamePasswordPackage.NetCafeTime$9.actionPerformed(NetCafeTime.java:444)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:357)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:809)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:850)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6267)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6032)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Codes I used to show popup menu:

```
public void showProjectMenu(MouseEvent e){
    JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
    JMenuItem menuItem;
    menuItem = new JMenuItem("Shutdown");
    menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "newline");
            try {
                shutdown();
            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NetCafeTime.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NetCafeTime.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
    menu.add(menuItem);
    menu.show(e.getComponent(),e.getX(),e.getY());
}
```

Mouse clicked event codes:

```
   private void jList1MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(evt)&&!jList1.isSelectionEmpty()&&jList1.locationToIndex(evt.getPoint())==jList1.getSelectedIndex()){
            showProjectMenu(evt);
        }
    }

    private void jList1MouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(evt)&&!jList1.isSelectionEmpty()&&jList1.locationToIndex(evt.getPoint())==jList1.getSelectedIndex()){
            showProjectMenu(evt);
        }
    }
```

Codes I used to show the popup menu:

```
public void showProjectMenu(MouseEvent e){
    JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
    JMenuItem menuItem;
    menuItem = new JMenuItem("Shutdown");
    menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "newline");
            try {
                shutdown();
            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NetCafeTime.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NetCafeTime.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
    menu.add(menuItem);
    menu.show(e.getComponent(),e.getX(),e.getY());
}
```

Codes I used to shutdown another pc by it's IP address:

```
public void shutdown()throws RuntimeException, IOException{
    String shutdownCommand;
    String operatingSystem = System.getProperty("os.name");
    if("Linux".equals(operatingSystem)||"Mac OS X".equals(operatingSystem)){
        shutdownCommand = "shutdown -h now";
    }else if("windows".equals(operatingSystem)){
        shutdownCommand = "shutdown.exe -s -t 0";
    }else{
        throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported operating system.");
    }
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shutdownCommand);
}
```

Problem is, I cannot get to shutdown the other pc...

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated and thanks...

Comment: Your way of comparing OS names should be improved. To contain any version of Windows OS, you should test: `System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("windows")`

Comment: Thank you sir, I made that improved. My question now is how to connect to other IP address so that I can establish a connection and then able to shutdown it. thanks.

Comment: For Windows OS, your shutdown command is lacking some info. Refer to `shutdown /?` for the full online documentation. But, this command requires a higher privilege. Your Java app should run in the administrator mode to make it work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says: `"Unsupported operating system"` and in your shutdown method this is the message of the `RuntimeException` which is thrown if the the current operating system is neigher "Linux", "Max OS X", nor "windows". So did you check what `System.getProperty("os.name")` actually returns?

EDIT: After re-reading your question I think you want to shut down the machine with the selected IP address. So in your shutdown method I think you'll have to connect to that machine first and execute the `shutdown` command there. This means you will need to run a server program on each machine you want to shutdown remotely. Either write your own one or install an SSH server on each and connect to the machine using [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to check [this example](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/OSInformation.shtml).As much as I understand `String operatingSystem = System.getProperty("os.name");` this code returns *Windows 2000* in this example.

[check this too](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-detect-os-in-java-systemgetpropertyosname/)